# Conditional function call without if

Tags: javascript

I used the following code a lot in my work

```
if (people === 'someone') {
  doSomething();
}
```

Is there any shorter way to do it ?

Comment: `people === 'someone' && doSomething();`!!!

Comment: @ArunPJohny Note that you shouldn't actually use that code. The `if` is far more readable.

Comment: @meagar yes, that is right

Comment: I have absolutely no clue why this question is downvoted so much. It's a specific and in my opinion reasonable question. As we see there are solutions and who say's that **if** is the most readable short conditioner along javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write like this:

`people === 'someone' && doSomething()`

It means if the left side is true, then right side will be take into action. If the left side is false, the statement end.

Note: I agree with meagar , `if` is more readable.

And in case you interested in how the logic operator work, see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Comment: bear in mind, if you wanted to add a `doSomethingElse()`, you wouldn't be able to do so using this form.

Answer (score -2):

You can use ternary operator. A Standard Ternary is simple, easy to read, and would look like this:

```
$value = ($people === 'someone') ? doSomething() : 'nothing';
```

or

```
echo ($people === 'someone') ? doSomething() : 'nothing';
```

Comment: both assume that `doSomething()` has a return....no indication of that in the question code and there is no `echo` in javascript